# Xpath and string under quotes

Tags: ios, string, xpath, quotes

Given the part of code:

```
<td class="tip-val">  
<div class = "bm-block">  
<a rel="nofollow" ..........................  
</a>  
</div>  
"2.04"  
</td>
```

I am trying to get the 2.04 (with or without quotes). According my knowledge, this `@"//td[@class='tip-val']"` or `@"//td[@class='tip-val']/text()"` should work, but it doesn't work.

I think there is something with quotes, but I am not sure. Anyone had similar problem?

Answer (score 1):

The path `//td[@class = 'tip-val']/text()[last()]` would select the last text child node of the `td` element so that way you will get the text node at the end, containing the string  
`"2.04"`
.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it also doesn't work, the result is the sam as without /text()... But what is general interesting is that I got 25 objects (which is supposed to get), but all of them are NULL. So all 3 versions mentioned here fetch NULLs, and that is why I suspect there is something with quotes...

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with the quotes.  **The problem has to do with your XPath matching multiple nodes where you're thinking that it's only matching one, and then surprising you by selecting the first node of the matching nodeset.**  This is a common gotcha with XPath 1.0.

The data that you're not showing us probably has another `td` element with a `class` attribute equal to `tip-val`.  As a test, try either deleting the other `td` elements or adding a unique id and selecting that on your targeted `td`.  As @MartinHonnen says, then `//td[@class = 'tip-val']/text()[last()]` should yield "2.04", with the quotes, and possibly with some surrounding newlines.

For completeness and future reference, there is one other possibility, although I suspect it's not the issue here.  It can be confusing when **adjacent fragmented text nodes** exist and [XPath 1.0 selects the first of those text nodes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-DOM-Level-3-XPath-20010618/xpath.html#TextNodes) rather than combining them together for us.  If your `td`-selecting XPath truly is selecting a single `td` element, and you're still surprised by what you're seeing as the last text node, investigate this sort of DOM fragmentation issue.